# Loss don't decrease when I'm training the VGG-base model to yield saliency maps

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, training-data, loss

My work is to get the saliency maps through a VGG-based network.
But the mse loss won't decrease as I imagine. So I cannot find why my loss dont decrease.
ps. training dataset is SALICON.
Here's the output:

```
training epoch 1, loss value is 0.041423566639423
training epoch 2, loss value is 0.041423123329878
training epoch 3, loss value is 0.041430559009314
training epoch 4, loss value is 0.041424177587032
...
training epoch 20, loss value is 0.041416928172112
```

And I try to change the optimizer, learning rate, loss function, but no one works.
Here's my codes:

```
def shuffle(photo, grdtr, shuffle=True):
    idx = np.arange(0, len(photo))
    if shuffle:
        np.random.shuffle(idx)
    photo_shuffle = [photo[i] for i in idx]
    grdtr_shuffle = [grdtr[i] for i in idx]

    return np.asarray(photo_shuffle), np.asarray(grdtr_shuffle)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create the model
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 48, 64, 3])
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 48 * 64, 1])
    h = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 48, 64, 1])

    y = deepnn(x)

    # define loss and optimizer

    # cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=(tf.clip_by_value(y,1e-8,tf.reduce_max(y))), labels=y_))
    y_ = tf.nn.softmax(y_, dim=1)

    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(y - y_, 2))
    # cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(y_ * tf.log(y_ / y)) #KL
    tf.summary.scalar('loss', cross_entropy)
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.001, beta1 = 0.9, beta2 = 0.999).minimize(cross_entropy)
    # do the training
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        ...

        # load the training data
        photos = np.load('./data/npy/SALICON100/photos_queue.npy')
        grdtrs = np.load('./data/npy/SALICON100/grdtrs_queue.npy')
        photos = photos / 255.0
        grdtrs = grdtrs / 255.0
        EPOCH = 20
        BATCH_SIZE = 20
        TRAINING_SET_SIZE = 20
        for j in range(EPOCH):
            # photos, grdtrs = shuffle(photos, grdtrs, shuffle=False)
            grdtrs = np.resize(grdtrs, [TRAINING_SET_SIZE, 48, 64, 20])
            grdtrs = np.reshape(grdtrs,[TRAINING_SET_SIZE, 48 * 64, 20])
            _, loss_value, pred_y = sess.run([train_step, cross_entropy,y],feed_dict={x: photos[:20], y_: grdtrs[:20]})
            if (j + 1) % 1 == 0:
                print('training epoch %d, loss value is %.15f' % (j + 1, loss_value))
            np.save('./data/20_photos_test/net_output.npy', pred)
            np.save('./data/20_photos_test/net_grdtrs.npy', grdtrs[:20])

                # stop the queue threads and properly close the session
       ...
```

And I put some codes about the tensors in the sess:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 48, 64, 3])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 48 * 64, 1])
y = deepnn(x)
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(y-y_sm,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code you posted you never actually run your train step. You need to call something along the line of `sess.run(train_step, feed_dict)` to actually train your network. If you do not train your network the loss obviosly will not be reduced.

Also are you sure that you want to use softmax on your labels?

Comment: Sorry, but actually i've called `sess.run` so i can get `loss_value`. I didnt post `sess.run` onto my question before. Sorry for that.

Comment: Your actual training code is not included in your code snippet. It is hard to tell what you are doing if you do not post the relevant code. For example loss_value is not assigned to in your code.

Comment: but i am not allowed to type more codes becuz it's too many codes here.

Comment: btw you always train on your first 20 images if you do not use shuffling. You should at least have an inner loop, which iterates over all the batches contained in your dataset.

Comment: it's only for a test. I want to ensure my codes work, so I only need to debug the first 20 images

Comment: You know that you are doing a softmax on your labels and then a MSE between the output of your network (does your network use softmax?) and the softmax output of your labels. You should probably visualize your training data. So the output of _y, x and y to make sure your data is in order.

Comment: Yep, I wanna build a full conv network, which means my ground truth is a image(distribution map) with the same size of the input. So I need to do softmax on the output of my network and the ground truth map.